# weak variable is becoming nil while writing testcase?

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, xctestcase

Hi I am writing a testcase  for a function in `ViewModel` in where I am using a weak variable,

While testing the function , the weak variable is becoming nil , also I instantiated it and provided value to that object just before calling the testing function. Why is it becoming nil , and then how do i test it!!!

**ALSO  I cannot make weak variable strong type!!, working on others code**

Compiler Warning - Instance will be immediately deallocated because property 'source' is 'weak'

**CODE**

```
func testFundTrip() {
     viewModel.source = SourceViewTypeMock()
     viewModel.fundTrip(trip)
}
```

**In ViewModel**

```
func fundTrip(_ trip: TravelTrip) {
        if let source = source { 
          // Here source is becoming nil ?? why 
        }
    }
```

Is there something with testcases methods with scopes of variables ?

Comment: Just a comment that might help, I think you might have an issue with how this is architected. If `SourceViewTypeMock` is a subclass of `UIView` that shouldn't be passed into the ViewModel. The point of having a ViewModel is to separate business logic from UI code. You should not import UIKit into a ViewModel. A VM should trigger networking code, take the response, format it, store the formatting somewhere and notify the view through a delegate/protocol, or callbacks etc.

Comment: @simon the thing is sourceviewtypemock is class which conforms to some sourcevietype protcol not using or importing uikit at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning is telling you exactly what's happening. You only have a weak pointer to a value, so nothing is going to keep your `SourceViewTypeMock` alive past the assignment statement. The solution is to create a strong reference. You need one that the compiler is not allowed to optimized out, so it has to be outside of this function. So you make it a property of the test case.

If it's immutable, you can do it this way:

```
class TheTestCase: XCTestCase {
    let sourceMock = SourceViewTypeMock()

    func testFundTrip() {
        viewModel.source = sourceMock
        viewModel.fundTrip(trip)
    }
}
```

If it's mutable, then you probably want to make sure you recreate it in `setUp`:

```
class TheTestCase: XCTestCase {
    var sourceMock: SourceViewTypeMock!

    override func setUp() {
        sourceMock = SourceViewTypeMock()
    }

    func testFundTrip() {
        viewModel.source = sourceMock
        viewModel.fundTrip(trip)
    }
}
```

Comment: Though i already did this by assigning a local var to sourceviewmock. Thanks for the insight!

Comment: A local variable isn't guaranteed to continue to exist after its last usage, so that strong reference could go away before the call to `fundTrip()`. It depends on the optimizer.

Comment: The local variable will always be there until the the function in activity stack or is in memory also the variable will have the refrence of weak variable so the arc count willl always be 1 until  the function is alive. So there will be no issues!

Comment: I don't think this is a correct understanding of ARC. ARC is free to deallocate any local variable that is not accessed later in the function. This is real thing that causes real crashes. I've debugged them myself.

Comment: I dont get it.still the arc count will be 1 local var is not weak why will it deallocate unless the func is deallocated , also im assigning the viewmodel var which is weak with local strong ref so until the local var is not nil the weak var also wont be nil ! Unless the vm is deallocated !

Comment: Because ARC can insert a release at any point after the last access to a local variable. So if you have code like `let x = SomeObject(); print(x)`, and never access `x` again in that function, then ARC can release `x` after the `print` completes. It does not have to wait until the end of the scope where `x` is valid. `let x = SomeObject; self.weakRef = x` is the same. `x` is the only strong reference, and ARC is free to release `x` immediately after the last use of it. Since `weakRef` doesn't create a strong reference, `x` can be destroyed at that point, and `weakRef` set to nil.

Comment: ARC doesn't *have* to insert that release; it's entirely a property of the optimizer. So in unoptimized code you may see one behavior, but when you turn on the optimizer you may see another behavior.

Comment: Ohh !! Very informative thanks rob. I will play with code now for this :p